# Add text to image when mouse over

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, web

I'm still new to web development (coming from desktop development) and my new boss already gave me a project.

I have to surround our company logo with images that link to other products of ours.
While I think I can surround the image with the logos, I want to add some text to the logos, to make it less confusing. I can imagine it to be quite... weird, for lack of a better word, if it's just a product's logo and nothing to tell the user what it is.

I have basic knowledge of PHP (I know how functions, constructors, classes, variables, etc. work, but have no real experience in it), but I don't know if this will help me in any way.

Here's an example of what I want to do (pseudo):

```
func onMouseOver(object m_obj) 
    m_obj.showCaption();
    m_obj.border = new Border(Effects.Glow, Colors.Blue);
end
```

I have no better way of demonstrating it, so sorry if it seems somewhat confusing.

If you're a Firefox user, open a new tab and hover over one of those images, I'm trying to achieve something similar to that.

The code:

```
  <head>
    <title>NetWork Team Vorschau</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index_style.css" >
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container" >
      <input class="sites_overview" type="image" src="http://www.sites-login.de/images/logo_sites.gif" value="Übersicht: Sites" /> <!-- I want this to show text when hovered over -->
      <img class="nwt_img" src="http://www.nwt.de/images/networkteam.png" />
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Cheers in advance for any and all helpful answers or pointers in the right direction!

Comment: Probably `.container img:hover {}` and `.container img:hover:after {}` ?

Comment: I'm guessing that's the CSS, right?
You'll have to excuse my ignorance, I have absolutely null experience with creating websites.

Comment: the title attribute is not enough for saying what the image meant to be?

Comment: @Vignesh No, there are supposed to be multiple images surrounding the company logo with different products and services.
I'd like to keep it sleek, yet readable.
I gave an example for Firefox users, but the same goes for Chrome. The border lights up, but I'd also like to add text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply in CSS:

```
.one:hover::after {
content:"Text when hovered";
position:absolute;
left:0;
}

<div class="container">
    <div class="one">
        <input class="sites_overview" type="image" src="http://www.sites-login.de/images/logo_sites.gif" value="Übersicht: Sites" />
    </div>
</div>
```

[**JDFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hg3p8jdd/)

EDIT: + one with glowing effect perhaps

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hg3p8jdd/1/)

Comment: Cheers. I'll give it a try and let you know.

Comment: Didn't quite work. The whole webpage started moving around rapidly as I hovered over the image.

Comment: I showed you basic code as a guide for you which will definitely work. You need to do lot more CSS to do exactly what you want and prevent these elements to do harm to your layout!

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can put

> `<title>Your text</title>`

inside `<img>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use JavaScript method ([onmouseover](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onmouseover)) or a jQuery method ([.mouseover()](https://api.jquery.com/mouseover/)). jQuery is the most used JavaScript Framework, check in the official page. JavaScript run in the client side, in the browser.

Regards